# Postgres. How to see logs of pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I need to do full logging of sql queries in the postgres itself; run pg_dump; and then all pg_dump actions will be in it (all sql queries). How to do it?

Comment: pg_dump only dumps schema objects and data.  It cannot output queries that have been run on the system.

If you want every query to appear in your database log, you will need to set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 in postgresql.conf, or using `ALTER SYSTEM SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;`.

Comment: What do you exactly need ? The SQL statements run by pg_dump ? if yes, run '`pg_dump --verbose`. If you want to see all SQL statements run in PostgreSQL instance for all databases set `log_statement=all` in postgresql.conf and run `pg_ctl reload`.